# Mantener la cuenta regresiva en Formularios

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Tengo el siguiente código, el cual pone un cronometro en cuenta regresiva y envia el formulario los datos que tenga a la BD pero el problema es que los usuarios al realizar ACTUALIZACION de la pagina web, el cronometro vuelve a los 2 minutos. hay alguna forma de que el relog mantenga el tiempo. Tengo el login realizada en PHP y mysql donde el acceso a este sitio es por el cargo es igual o menor que 3 entonces accede a la pagina y sino entonces no muestra la pagina.

```
<?php 
  include("../sesion.class.php");
$sesion=new sesion();
$cargo=$sesion->get("cargo");
$usuario=$sesion->get("usuario");
if ($cargo=='3') { ?>
// se escribe el contenido de la pagina web


//fin del sitio web
<?php  }else{
  echo "No eres Administrador y No tienes Permiso para ver esta pagina ";
  echo "<a href ='../index.php' > REGRESAR </a>";
}?>


<script>

var salida = document.getElementById("tiempo"),
    minutos = 2,
    segundos = 0,
    intervalo = setInterval(function(){
        if (--segundos < 0){
            segundos = 59;
            minutos--;
        }

        salida.innerHTML = minutos + ":" + (segundos < 10 ? "0" + segundos : segundos);

        if (!minutos && !segundos){
            clearInterval(intervalo);
            document.getElementById("test").submit();
        }
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

este es el formulario

```html
<form action="accion.php" method="post" id="test">
<label id = "tiempo">02:00 </label><br>
<input type='text' name='name' >

<button type="submit" name="test" id="test" class="btn-u btn-block rounded">Siguiente >>>> </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Comentas en tus tags que usas html5. No has evaluado el uso de localStorage?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes lograrlo con cookies, te ilustro con un ejemplo:

```js
var timeOut = parseInt(Cookies("Read", "AutoSubmit")),
 maxTime = 2 * 60 * 1000; // Tiempo de Espera (En Minutos)

if ( !timeOut ) {
 date = new Date();
 timeOut = date.getTime() + maxTime;
 Cookies("Write", "AutoSubmit", timeOut);
}
date = new Date();
timeOut = (parseInt(timeOut) - date.getTime());

if (timeOut > 0) {
 messg = "Envio del Formulario (en "+ (timeOut) +"ms)";
 setTimeout(function (){
  document.forms[0].submit();
 }, timeOut);
} else {
 messg = "Envio del Formulario ...En Proceso.";
 Cookies("Remove", "AutoSubmit");
 document.forms[0].submit();
}
document.getElementById("messg").innerHTML=messg;

// Rutina para manejar Cookies (puedes usar la que gustes)
function Cookies(action, name, value, days, expires) {
  switch (action) {
    case "Read":
      var myCookies = "; "+document.cookie+"; ",
          myCookie  = "",
          Index     = myCookies.indexOf("; "+name+"=")+name.length+3;

      if (Index >= name.length+3)
        myCookie = myCookies.substring(Index,myCookies.indexOf("; ",Index));

      return unescape(myCookie);

    case "Write":
      var myCookie = name+"="+escape(value);
      if (days && !expires) {
        var expires = new Date();
        expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * days));
      }
      if (expires)
        myCookie += "; expires="+expires.toGMTString();

      document.cookie = myCookie+";"; 
      return unescape(myCookie);

    case "Remove":
      var myCookie = name+"=; expires=0";
      document.cookie = myCookie+";";
      return unescape(myCookie);

    default:
      var massage = null;
      massage +="use: Cookies(action, name[, value[, days[, expires]]])\n";
      massage +="     where: action is 'Read', 'Write', 'Remove'\n";
      massage +="            name is Name of Cookies\n";
      massage +="            value is data to Write\n";
      massage +="            days is number of days to expires a Cookies.\n";
      massage +="          & expires is date to expires a Cookies.\n";
      alert(massage);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Contactos</h1>
<pre>
 <form name="contacto">
    nombre <input name="name">
  telefono <input name="phone">
  <hr>
 <input type="submit">
 </form>
</pre>
<div id="messg">
</div>
```

Aquí te dejo el ejemplo funcional en [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/ohrdpraw/) (no da error)

Answer (score 0):

Usando solo javascript no lo veo factible, tendrías que apoyarte en una base de datos y en un lenguaje tipo php para hacerlo, ademas de una pantalla de login

la idea seria que cuando entres a la pagina registres un id correspondiente al usuario  usando variables de sesión con este id puedes registrar en base de datos la fecha en la que entro a la pagina, con la fecha registrada cada vez que recargue pagina verificas comparando la hora actual con su registro cuanto tiempo le queda antes de que se acabe el tiempo del contador

Comment: Las publicaciones en este sitio deben ir directo al asunto principal. Favor de omitir fórmulas de cortesía que no aportan nada a la descripción del problema ni de la solución.

Comment: @Jorge, si es posible controlar un temporizador con javascript, incluso si refresca la pagina (es por esto que el contador lo almacenamos en una cookies), he dejado un ejemplo de como hacerlo, Saludos!! ;))...

Answer (score 0):

gracias por la aclaracion, lo intente adaptar a la pagina pero el problema es el siguiente:
- son un total de 5 paginas  de una evaluacion  online que estoy creando: eva1.php (proceso_eva1.php)eva2.php(proceso_eva2.php), etc.
- tendria que funcionar de la siguiente forma: que el usuarion al iniciar el examen el cronometro no tendria que reiniciarse cuando refresca la pagina (actualizar la pagina) pero ADAPTANDO el codigo hace ese proceso pero me guarda todas la paginas de una, hasta el final, cual seria el problema?.